# Getting started for C# AspNet Core and Heroku

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, heroku

There are a number of "getting started" pages for Heroku in a number of languages. As far as I have been able to determine C# is not on the list. Where do I go for "getting started" with ASP.NET Core (3.1) with C#? My app is an ASP.NET Core Single Page App using Angular if that more clearly defines the app.

Comment: Heroku doesn't support ASP.NET Core natively. But as a walkaround, you can deploy the ASP.NET Core app with  `Docker`.

Comment: I have seen that suggestion before. But being new to Heroku I am not sure how to proceed, I guess I need a quick start for Docker,